# A function $f$ on $[0,1]$ sending a rational $x = p/q$ to $1/q$ and $0$ otherwise

Tags: solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

> Let $f$ be a function on $[0,1]$ such that for $x \in [0,1]$ belonging to $\mathbb{Q}$, i.e., $x = p/q$ for some integers $p,q$, we set $f(x) = 1/q$. If $x$ is irrational, then $f(x) = 0$. Is $f$ (Lebesgue) measurable?

I'm trying to prove that $f$ is measurable by fixing $\alpha > 0$ and proving that the set $$E_\alpha =\{x \in [0,1] : f(x) > \alpha\}$$ is measurable. But clearly $E_\alpha \subset \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ which is countable and has measure zero so $E_\alpha$ has measure zero. This is true for any such $\alpha$. If $\alpha$ is zero then $E_\alpha$ is clearly $\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$ and if $\alpha$ is negative then $E_\alpha = [0,1]$ which has measure $1$.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: You should also mention that $\{x: f(x) >\alpha\}=[0,1]$ if $\alpha <0$. $f$ is actually Borel measurable so you don't have to bring in measure of any set for this.

Comment: That about covers it! Well done. A shorter proof might use the more general fact that, if $f(x) = g(x)$ almost everywhere and $g$ is measurable, then $f$ is also measurable. In this case, $f(x) = 0 $ almost everywhere.

Comment: You should specify “for some coprime integer $p,q$, with $q>0$” in the definition of $f$; otherwise the function is not well-defined.